# Dynamic Textbox Using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

in asp.net TextBox will create pressure to button1's. Button2 to the pressure inside the TextBox data consisting of label1 my yazdırıca. I tried to do it like this gives an error.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
button1_click{

 TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "a";
        txt.EnableViewState = true;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(txt);

 }

Button2_click{
 TextBox deneme= Panel1.FindControl("a") as TextBox;
        Label1.Text = deneme.Text; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you create your control, on the first click, the control shown on the page and exist.

On the second click the page **is not know any more about that text control** because you did not save that information somewhere and because only you know that some time in the past you create it.

So on this code you have:

```
Button2_click{  
     TextBox deneme= Panel1.FindControl("a") as TextBox;
     // here the deneme is null ! and you get the exception !
     // the deneme is not exist on the second click, not saved anywhere
     Label1.Text = deneme.Text;  
}
```

The solution is to keep on viewstate what control you create and how, and re-create them on PageInit. Alternative you can redesign your page and think a different approach to that, eg you can have the TextControl's all ready on page hidden, and just open them.

Answer (score -1):

```
   Button2_click{  
TextBox txt = (TextBox)Panel1.FindControl("a");

Label Label1 = new Label();
Label1.Text=txt.Texxt;
}
```